# How to use two things in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Beginner have question :)

How to use two defined things in jQuery in the same time?

e.g.

```
$div1 = $('#div1'),
$div2 = $('#div2');

if($('#checbox1').is("checked")){
   ($div1,$div2).hide()
}
```

**At this moment I use:**

```
if($('#checbox1').is("checked")){
    $('#div1,#div2').hide()
}
```

But when I have long name of divs, this is a lot lines of code.

Thank you!

Comment: you can use element base selector to get all div

Comment: can you provide you html structure

Comment: @PranayRana - You can look code there http://tnij.at/registerForm - all it works in jQuery changing - E.g hide some div if checkbox is checked, makes required field etc. I can't do it in another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already defined variables, You can use [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

> Create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched elements.

```
//Assuming
$div1 = $('#div1'),
$div2 = $('#div2');

$div1.add($div2).hide()
```

Comment: that will cause issue if thre are more then one div element, what if there are 10 div

Comment: @PranayRana, OP is clearly asking for already defined object. Obviously using common name would be better

Comment: @Satpal - this one is `$('#div1,#div2').hide()` better then what you suggested

Comment: @PranayRana. OP might be using objects i.e. `$div1, $div2` somewhere. Why do you think thats the only statement in the script

Comment: @PranayRana - I do a from which has very long names - and there is a lot of changing, that why I want to avoid repeat a lot of time that same, because then is very long code.

Answer (score 3):

Give them same class name, and `$('.class').hide();` will do the stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Sidhanshu_'s answer.

```
<div class="divs" id="#div1"></div>
<div class="divs" id="#div2"></div>


<script>
    $('.divs').hide();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `class` over `id` and apply the class to the function. Like this:

```
if($('checbox1') is checked{
    ('.div1').hide();
    }
```

Comment: I use it now, but classes and IDs are very long... and I want e.g. hide a few divs, so then is problem, because code is very long.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using below:

```
[$div1, $div2].map(elem => elem.hide());
```